# Formatting a python dictionary of tuples?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following output at the moment:

```
{ ('JAIL','A'): 20, ('BAIL','J'): 50, ('ZERO','D'): 80, ('LIME', 'A'): 24 }
```

I want to sort this dictionary by the first string of the tuple in the dictionary. Then I want to show the output as follows:

```
BAIL -> J 50
JAIL -> A 20
LIME -> A 24
ZERO -> D 80
```

Comment: Iterate over `for key, value in sorted(the_dictionary).items():`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sorted` method

```
myDict = { ('JAIL','A'): 20, ('BAIL','J'): 50, ('ZERO','D'): 80, ('LIME', 'A'): 24 }
for l, v in sorted(myDict.items()):
    print "{} -> {} {}".format(l[0], l[1], v)
```

**Output**

```
BAIL -> J 50
JAIL -> A 20
LIME -> A 24
ZERO -> D 80
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) and tuple unpacking:

```
>>> myDict = {('JAIL','A'):20, ('BAIL','J'):50, ('ZERO','D'):80, ('LIME','A'):24}
>>> for (word, ch), value in sorted(myDict.items()):
...     print('{} -> {} {}'.format(word, ch, value))
...
BAIL -> J 50
JAIL -> A 20
LIME -> A 24
ZERO -> D 80
```